# Importance of the Prophecy and Moses' Prophecy in the 13 Principles

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rambam

Rambam's 13 Principles (as a part of his Interpretation of the 10th Chapter of the Mishnah in Sanhedrin) brings #6 - [Existence of the Prophecy](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.1?lang=bi&p2=Rambam_on_Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.1.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) (see the link for the English translation):

> **היסוד הששי: הנבואה**, והוא שידע אדם שזה מין האדם ימצא בהם בעלי טבעים ממדות מעולות מאד ושלימות גדולה ונפשותיהן נכונות עד שהן מקבלות צורת השכל אחר כן ידבק אותו השכל האנושי בשכל הפועל ונאצל ממנו עליו אצילות נכבד ואלה הם הנביאים וזו היא הנבואה...

And #7 - The Prophecy of Moses and the 4 ways it was different from all others:

> **היסוד השביעי: נבואת משה רבינו ע"ה** והוא שנאמין כי הוא אביהם של כל הנביאים אשר היו מלפניו ואשר קמו מאחריו כלם הם תחתיו במעלה והוא היה הנבחר מכל מין האדם אשר השיג מידיעתו יתברך יותר מכל מה שהשיג או ישיג שום אדם שנמצא או שימצא וכי הוא ע"ה הגיע התעלותו מן האנושות עד המעלה המלאכותית ונכלל במעלת המלאכים לא נשאר מסך שלא קרעו ונכנס ממנו ולא מנעו מונע גופני  וכו'

Further, in #8, he states that the Torah is given by Hashem in whole and whoever might think that Moses added a single verse is a Koyfer.

The question is: given #8, **why those two principles (#6 and #7) are the pillars of Judaism in Rambam's view**? What is the practical implementation of those beliefs/disbeliefs?

Comment: Good question...why do the practical implementations matter? It's a matter of belief? If someone doesn't believe one of those three, they could feel free to change the Torah since *maybe* Moshe made a mistake chas v'shalom?

Comment: https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=t4TclPFTzfQC&lpg=PP1&dq=prophecy%20rambam%20gutnick&pg=PP1#v=onepage -- this sefer analyzes the pillar 6 and 7 in depth, and this one analyzes 8 and 9 in depth -- https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=r54bbqIYAZgC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false . They are worth reading and free online. They discuss this.

Comment: @Menachem The book's great! If I understood it right, Rambam himself states #6 is the Prophecy is secondary to Torah from Heaven. Weird.

Comment: Because Torah is the ultimate prophecy, that lays down the rules for all other prophecies.